# Apache rewrite rules and wordpress problem

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I tried to fix my problem by using wordpress rewrite rules but sadly it took me so long I tried this approach. I got it working for one of my simpler problems but now I can't get it to work for my two variable rewrite.

```
# START Custom rules.
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^examentraining/vak/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=1316&vakname=$1&level=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^examentraining/training/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagename=examentraining/training&trainingid=$1 [L]

# FIN customrules

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The second rule rewrites `index.php?pagename=examentraining/training$trainingid=VAKID => /examentraining/training/VAKID/`. 
This one works and has been tested.

I would like my first example to also work, this one needs to rewrite
`/index.php?p=1316&vakname=VAKNAME&level=LEVELNAME => /examentraining/vak/VAKNAME/LEVELNAME/`.

`LEVELNAME` and `VAKNAME` are both strings that should be able to contain A-Z,a-z,_,&.
I have tested this rewrite rule on multiple online tester but when I use it with wordpress it keeps failing.

I enabled logging for .htaccess and I can see that the rewrite is functioning correctly but I can't follow it afterwards.

The log: https://gist.github.com/ITWarrior/9292036

I hope somebody can help me, I have to get this done and I have tried al sorts of ways.

EDIT 1

I added `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` to my plugin.
Now requesting /examentraining/vak/natuurkunde/vwo gets me to /examentraining/vak/natuurkunde/vwo but with an 404 not found wordpress error.
The log of this request: https://gist.github.com/ITWarrior/9294435
The rewrite works fine and entering the url after the first rewrite actually gets me to the correct page (/index.php?p=1316&vakname=aardrijkskunde&level=vwo).

Comment: Did you disable the redirect_canonical code in WordPress?

Comment: @Otto I just disabled the edirect_canonical and I think it has brought me a closer to the solution. When I entered the url /examentraining/vak/natuurkunde/vwo I used to end up on /examentraining/vak/ and now I get to /examentraining/vak/natuurkunde/vwo/ which returns an 404 not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of fiddling around and trying all sorts of tricks, I finally figured it out. There we're two things I was doing wrong, I wanted wordpress to be able to access get last two value's in between slashes as GET parameters when an url like this `/examentraining/vak/VAKNAME/LEVELNAME/` is submitted to Wordpress. 
`p=1316&vakname=VAKNAME&level=LEVELNAME => /examentraining/vak/VAKNAME/LEVELNAME/` is incorrect because it worked the other way around. But when I reversed the rewrite rule it still didn't work.

I still have to figure out the exact reason but I never managed to get it working via the .htaccess file. Then I came across the following class by Kyle E Gentile.

```
<?php
/*
//Author Kyle E Gentile
//To use this class you must first include the file.  
//After including the file, you need to create an options array.  For example:
$options = array(
    'query_vars' => array('var1', 'var2'),
    'rules' => array('(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]')
);
//After creating our $option array, 
//we will need to create a new instance of the class as below:
$rewrite = new Add_rewrite_rules($options);
//You must pass the options array, this way. (If you don't there could be problems) 
//Then you can call the filters and action functions as below:
add_action('wp_head', array(&$rewrite, 'flush_rules'));
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$rewrite, 'add_rewrite_rules') );
add_filter( 'query_vars', array(&$rewrite, 'add_query_vars') );
//That is it.
*/

//prevent duplicate loading of the class if you are using this in multiply plugins
if(!class_exists('add_rewrite_rules')){

    class Add_rewrite_rules{

        var $query_vars;
        var $rules;

        function __construct($options){
            $this->init($options);
        }

        function init($options){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        function rules_exist(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $has_rules = TRUE;

            foreach($this->rules as $key => $value){
                if(!in_array($value, $wp_rewrite->rules)){
                    $has_rules = FALSE;
                }   
            }

            return $has_rules;
        }

        //to be used add_action with the hook 'wp_head'
        //flushing rewrite rules is labor intense so we better test to see if our rules exist first
        //if the rules don't exist flush its like after a night of drinking  
        function flush_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            if(!$this->rules_exist()){
                //echo "flushed"; // If want to see this in action uncomment this line and remove this text and you will see it flushed before your eyes
                $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
            }
        }

        //filter function to be used with add_filter() with the hook "query_vars"
        function add_query_vars($query_vars){

            foreach($this->query_vars as $var){
                $query_vars[] = $var;
            }

            return $query_vars;
        }

        //to be used with a the add_action() with the hook "generate_rewrite_rules"
        function add_rewrite_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $wp_rewrite->rules = $this->rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
        }

    }

}
?>
```

I added the following function to the init of my plugin.

```
public function rewriteRules()
{
//Add the query variables to the list so wordpress doesn't discard them or worse use them to try and find by itself what page to serve.
    $options = array(
        'query_vars' => array('trainingid', 'vakname'),
        'rules' =>
            array( 'uncategorized/vak/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?p=1316&vakname=$matches[1]&level=$matches[2]'
            )
    );

    //I use a autoloader but if you don't you have to include the class.
    //include_once('path/to/AddRewriteRules.php');
    $rewrite = new AddRewriteRules($options);
    add_action('wp_head', array(&$rewrite, 'flush_rules'));
    add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$rewrite, 'add_rewrite_rules'));
    add_filter('query_vars', array(&$rewrite, 'add_query_vars'));


}
```

This solved the problem but there was a step before this, as you might have noticed I wanted to match `examentraining/vak/VAKNAME/LEVELNAME/` but I ended up matching `uncategorized/vak/VAKNAME/LEVELNAME/`. This is because for some reason either Wordpress SEO or Wordpress itself messes with my request. To find the correct request URL use the amazing [debug bar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/). It tells you exactly what request is coming in and what rules have been matched.

I hope this helps anybody!